# chronoforms not showing up on my website

Tags: php, joomla, chronoforms

I cant figure out why my forms are not showing up on my site. This is the error message:

> "Warning: require_once(/hermes/bosnaweb03a/b302/ipw.proliter/public_html/411tech/newsite): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /hermes/bosnaweb03a/b302/ipw.proliter/public_html/411tech/newsite/components/com_chronocontact/chronocontact.php on line 17 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php-5.3.13/lib/php') in /hermes/bosnaweb03a/b302/ipw.proliter/public_html/411tech/newsite/components/com_chronocontact/chronocontact.php on line 17

This is my chronocontact.php form

```
<?php
  /**
   * CHRONOFORMS version 3.1
   * Copyright (c) 2006 Chrono_Man, ChronoEngine.com. All rights reserved.
   * Author: Chrono_Man (ChronoEngine.com)
   * See readme.html.
   * @license       GNU/GPL
   * Visit http://www.ChronoEngine.com for regular update and information.
   **/

  /* ensure that this file is called by another file */
  defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

  /**
   * Load the HTML class
   */
  require_once( JApplicationHelper::getPath( 'front_html' ) );
  require_once( JApplicationHelper::getPath( 'class' ) );

  require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
  require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
  $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
  $mainframe->initialise();

  //load chronoforms classes
  require_once( JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'libraries'.DS.'chronoform.php');
  require_once( JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'libraries'.DS.'mails.php');
  require_once( JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'libraries'.DS.'customcode.php');
  require_once( JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'libraries'.DS.'chronoformuploads.php');
  require_once( JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'libraries'.DS.'plugins.php');


  jimport( 'joomla.application.component.controller' );
  global $mainframe;
  if(JRequest::getVar('chronoformname')){
    JRequest::setVar('chronoformname', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/', '', JRequest::getVar('chronoformname')));
  }
  $formname = JRequest::getVar('chronoformname');
  if ( !$formname ) {
    $params =& $mainframe->getPageParameters('com_chronocontact');
    $formname = $params->get('formname');
  }

  $MyForm =& CFChronoForm::getInstance($formname);

  if(!$MyForm->formrow->id){
    echo "There is no form with this name or may be the form is unpublished, Please check the form and the url and the form management";
    return;
  }

  if($MyForm->formparams('dbconnection') == "Yes"){
    eval ("?>".$MyForm->formrow->dbclasses);
  }

  $posted = JRequest::get( 'post' , JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW );
  /**
   * Main switch statement
   */
  switch( $task ) {
    case 'send':
      uploadandmail($formname);
      break;
    case 'extra':
      doextratask($formname);
      break;
    default:
      showform($formname, $posted);
      break;
    }
  /**
   * End of main page
   *
   */

  /**
   * Display the form for entry
   *
   */
  function showform($formname, $posted)
  {
    global $mainframe;
    $database =& JFactory::getDBO();

    $MyForm =& CFChronoForm::getInstance($formname);
    $MyForm->showForm($formname, $posted);
    `enter code here` //HTML_ChronoContact::showform( $MyForm->formrow, $posted);
  }

  /**
   * Respond to a submitted form
   *
   */
  function uploadandmail($formname)
  {
    global $mainframe;
    $database =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $posted = JRequest::get( 'post' , JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW );

    //Load Chronoforms Classes
    $MyForm =& CFChronoForm::getInstance($formname);
    $MyFormData = $MyForm->getForm(JRequest::getVar( 'chronoformname'));
    if($MyFormData){
      //fine
    }else{
      $mainframe->enqueueMessage('Error processing this form, form was not loaded!');
      return;
    }

    // Block SPAM through the submit URL
    if((!JRequest::checkToken()) && $MyForm->formparams('checkToken', 1))
    {
      echo "You are not allowed to access this URL";
      return;
    }
    if ( empty($posted) ) {
      echo "You are not allowed to access this URL directly, POST array is empty";
      return;
    }   

    if(JRequest::getVar('action') == 'extra'){
      $extraid = JRequest::getVar( 'extraid');
      $MyForm->doExtra($MyForm->formrow->name, $extraid, $posted);
    }

    $MyForm->submitForm($MyForm->formrow->name, $posted, $MyForm->formparams('useCurrent', false));
  }

  function doextratask($formname){
    global $mainframe;
    $database =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $posted = JRequest::get( 'post' , JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW );

    $MyForm =& CFChronoForm::getInstance($formname);
    $extraid = JRequest::getVar( 'extraid');
    $MyForm->doExtra($formname, $extraid, $posted);
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are running what looks like version 3 of ChronoForms which should run correctly on Joomla! v1.5. It will not run on later versions of Joomla!.

Line 17 is a standard Joomla! line that is loading this file /components/com_chronocontact/chronocontact.html.php

If that does not exist in your installation then it will cause this error.

If it is missing then the most likely reason is that your host has run a virus scan on your site and removed the file as possibly dangerous - it is perfectly safe but has some code that causes false positives. You should ask them to white-list it and then replace the file from the installation package.

Comment: Okay thanks I will look into that and get back to you!